# Handle MasterPage event on ContentPage

Tags: asp.net, events

I have a button on my MasterPage and I want the ContentPage to handle the Click event of the button.  Here's what I have so far:

```
//Event in MasterPage
public event EventHandler Search_Submit;

//ButtonClick event in MasterPage
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Search_Submit != null)
        {               
            Search_Submit(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }


//EventHandler in Page_Init on ContentPage
Master.Search_Submit += new EventHandler(Master_Search_Submit);

//Search_Submit event in ContentPage
private void Master_Search_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Perform appropriate action...
    }
```

This all works - however, I would like to pass a value with the EventArgs.  I believe I need to create a custom EventArgs class that inherits from EventArgs and has my custom properties.  However, my when I do that I get the following error: No overload for 'Master_Search_Submit' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your event to use the EventHandler delegate.  A delegate is a pointer to a function, it defines the signature the responding method must have.  The signature for the EventHandler delegate is:

```
delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

In .NET 2.0 there is a generic EventHandler delegate that allows you to specify the EventArgs type you would like to use.

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Search_Submit;
```

Now you can use an event handler with the signature

```
void EventArgs<TArgs>(object sender, TArgs e) where TArgs: EventArgs
```

In your case this would be:

```
void Master_Search_Submit(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
```

Comment: I have changed my event declaration like you mention, and changed my event handler to use my custom EventArgs class.  However, I am still getting the same error with the line in the Page_Init class (see original post for code).

Comment: I changed that line to Master.Search_Submit += new EventHandler<SearchEventArgs>(Master_Search_Submit); and it worked properly.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Either you'll have to pass the your arguments as an EventArgs, and cast it in your handler:

```
private void Master_Search_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MyEventArgs mea = (MyEventArgs)e;
    //Perform appropriate action...
}
```

Or you'll have to define a delegate that expects your custom event args class:

```
 public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs mae);
 public event MyEvent myEvent

 myEvent += new MyEventHandler(Master_Search_Submit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommandEventHandler instead of EventHandler delegate.