# UpdatePanel and two content placeholder areas from a master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, partial-page-refresh

I have a "legacy" ASP.NET site I'd like to improve a bit. One area I'd like to do something about is page updates - for now, it's always full page updates, but I'd like to start using partial updates.

I was hoping to be able to use the ASP.NET `UpdatePanel` for this - but I'm a bit stuck on how to get this to work for me.

I have a master page which defines several content placeholders - simplified it looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.master.cs" Inherits="WebForms_Default" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>MyTitle</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="myForm" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="smgrMaster" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
         <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
         </Scripts>
      </asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="cphSearch" />
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="cphContent" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

On my content page, my grid is showing the data inside the `cphContent` area - and in my `cphSearch` area I have a number of input controls - a `RadioButtonList` and two `DropDowns`. Whenever something in those controls changes, for now, a postback is issued (they have `AutoPostback="true"` set).

My problem is: how do I tell my `UpdatePanel` (which I'm trying to wrap around my grid in the `cphContent` area) to "listen" for postbacks from those three controls from `cphSearch` ?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView>
         // grid view defined here
      </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID=".. what values to put here?? .." />
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID=".. - what values to put here?? .." />
   </Triggers>
```

When I add my `<asp:UpdatePanel>`, I get a section `<Triggers>`, but those controls in the `cphSearch` content area aren't visible, so I guess I can't really add them as update triggers, correct?

Either I'm totally not getting it (absolutely possible!), or I'm missing an obvious step / trick to get this to work - or it's just not possible. Let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its not necessary to put `Triggers` all the time when you are not able to find control for `Triggers` some event just use updatepanel without `triggers`

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSearch" runat="Server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateSearch" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       your searching controls
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="Server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateContent" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        your grid
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

this will update whole grids, search controls and it will also handles AutoPostBack event but dnt forget to put Update `<asp:UpdateProgress>` control to see work is in process...

Comment: Not sure why - but this does seem to work - thanks! I was always under the impression you had to tell an UpdatePanel what events would trigger a partial page update...

Answer (score 0):

From the information, I assume you have your search controls on MasterPage that are common to all pages. One way would be to expose an event from your masterpage and handle it on your contentpage. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074761/handle-masterpage-event-on-contentpage).

Upon your DDL selectedIndexChanged event you raise this event. Inside the handler of this event on contentPage you call updateContent.Update().

I think the solution lies somewhere along those lines.

Comment: Not exactly - those search controls are dependent on the content shown - they're inside a ContentPlaceHolder (defined in the master page) - but they're **not** on the master page itself (nor are they the same for all content pages)

Comment: So your GV and Search Controls are part of same contentpage you mean? I am not getting the clear picture. Can you update your code that includes search control as well.

Comment: No - the search controls are in one file and are placed onto the `cphSearch` container, while the gridview is in another file and is placed onto the `cphContent` container

Comment: another file? you mean they are independent UserControls?

Comment: Yes exactly - two separate user controls that are being put onto separate content areas on a page that is based on a master page